# Compatibility of classes with distinct owners

Tags: c++, design-patterns

**Given**:

```
class Foo1 { 
 public:
  typedef Foo2 owner;
};
class Foo2 {
 public:
  typedef Foo1 vassal;
  typedef Foo3 owner;
};
//... and so on 
class FooN {
 public:
  typedef FooNm1 vassal;
  typedef ExternalType owner;  // problem
  owner* owner();
};
```

Question:

How to associate class hierarchy with external owner, preserving compatibility between classes of distinct owners.

**Problems**:

1. If we make FooN a template with owner as a template parameter, then every class of the Foo{N} hierarchy will be infected by this owner via dependency chain.
2. If we make an interface FooNOwner for external owner to inherit from, then we face need of dynamic casting to move from algorithms on the Foo{N} hierarchy to an actual owner.

Is there a design pattern to solve my problem?

Example of a situation where these problems arise:
You have a structure that consists of Foo{N} classes. It is used for fast searching and a query from it returns list of Foo{N} objects. I want to get a pointer of concrete type ExternalOwner* to an external owner from a returned FooN object, so avoiding dynamic casting. At the same time I want to operate with Foo{N}(maybe without FooN) objects with distinct FooN::owner without looking back on this difference.

**Update:**

Maybe the only valid way to do this is to define common Owner interface and to overload it by owners for usage in the context where different owner classes take place. This interface thereby is defined by a context of its usage (but FooN has nothing to do with the context of FooN::owner usage). This is the problem I was trying to solve initially - separate different tasks, this approach does not help me.

**My solution**

I ended up with double dispatch. If I add virtual void apply(FooOwnerVisitor*) = 0; function to FooOwner and define FooOwnerVisitor interface nearby, then I can add any functionality for FooOwner derivatives without affecting FooN hierarchy and without dynamic_cast.

Comment: I do not understand your second problem. Can you give an example of what kind of algorithms you want to apply?

Comment: 1. What do you expect instead?
2. What is the problem exactly?

Comment: The question suffers from willy-nilly generalization and needless vagueness. Post your actual code. Or at least a concrete example that compiles.

Comment: "structure consists of FooN classes" - do you mean `struct { Foo1 f1; Foo2 f2; ... };` or a data structure somehow (e.g. boost variant/any) storing any Foo{N} object, perhaps tying in to "query...return list of FooN", which otherwise begs the Q "what kind of list?"  They're distinct types with no common base, you can't have a std::list of them. P1: true. Maybe you can use virtual functions rather than dynamic casting? Or `template <typename Any_Foo> void f(Any_Foo& f) { vassal v; ... }`?

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y, @Alexander, @Alf I've added the example, please see. My problem is how to implement FooN::owner to know actual external owner class, but not infect Foo{N} classes with that knowledge. Maybe one workaround is to encapsulate dynamic casting into FooN::owner interface...

Comment: @Riga: This seems to be an awfully complicated design. Can you describe the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @Tony, I mean for example tree<Foo3>, query from this tree will give my Foo3 objects that will give me FooN::owner by sequential owner() invoke. So i do not need to cast between Foo{N} classes but I want them to provide distinct FooN::owner in the end of chain, or maybe to have functionality to provide it without dynamic cast.

Comment: @Space, ok, imagine that you are solving problem in K-dimensional space, Foo{N} hierarchy represents objects in one (let in be F-th} of the dimensions of that space, so for algorithms that deal with this dimension it is sufficient to work with Foo{N} only. K-dimensional object (super-object) is represented via some subspaces in every dimension. In L-th dimension it is presented via Foo{N} objects. I want these Foo{N} objects to be able to return the type of super-object it is owned by and to work seamlessly with Foo{N} objects that is owned by a super-object of another type.

Comment: @Space, this leads to a solution of specifying owner by enum value, but this is the same approach as dynamic_cast, as I understand.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y, @Alexander, @Alf please, see update to the initial post, I believe this will explain my problem.

Comment: @Riga: If you have your own solution, you can post it as an answer and accept, to mark this question as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with double dispatch. If I add virtual void apply(FooOwnerVisitor*) = 0; function to FooOwner and define FooOwnerVisitor interface nearby, then I can add any functionality for FooOwner derivatives without affecting FooN hierarchy and without dynamic_cast. So my problem actually wa two problems tha have own solutions. First - how to make FooN classes from different owners compatible - inherit from owner interface. Second - how to avoid dynamic casting of FooNOwner derived classes - use Visitor pattern. One must consider to separate a problem into smaller ones and combine atomic solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think anyone's clear on your requirement, but this is my best guess at addressing it... illustrating how to handle what you're calling the "dependency chain" in a template solution.  If this doesn't help, but has any relevancy, then explaining it and the problems would help people help you.  If you want to apply algorithmic loops over the `Foo<>` objects I can illustrate how to do that....

```
#include <iostream>

struct Abstract_Bar
{
    virtual void f() const = 0;
};

struct Bar1 : Abstract_Bar
{
    void f() const { std::cout << "Bar1\n"; }
};

struct Bar2 : Abstract_Bar
{
    void f() const { std::cout << "Bar2\n"; }
};

template <int N>
struct Foo
{
    typedef Foo<N - 1> Lower;
    typedef Foo<N + 1> Higher;

    void f() const { std::cout << "Foo<N>\n"; }

    Higher* higher_;
};

template <>
struct Foo<1>
{
    typedef Foo<2> Higher;

    void f() const { std::cout << "Foo<1>\n"; }

    Higher* higher_;
};

template <>
struct Foo<4>
{
    typedef Foo<3> Lower;
    typedef Abstract_Bar Higher;

    void f() const { std::cout << "Foo<4>\n"; }

    Higher* higher_;
};

int main()
{
    Foo<1> foo1;
    Foo<2> foo2;
    Foo<3> foo3;
    Foo<4> foo4;
    foo1.higher_ = &foo2;
    foo2.higher_ = &foo3;
    foo3.higher_ = &foo4;
    Bar1 bar1;
    foo4.higher_ = &bar1;

    foo1.f();
    foo2.f();
    foo3.f();
    foo4.f();

    foo1.higher_->f();
    foo2.higher_->f();
    foo3.higher_->f();
    foo4.higher_->f();

    // switch to another type of "Bar"...
    Bar2 bar2;
    foo4.higher_ = &bar2;
    foo4.higher_->f();
}
```

Comment: @Riga: you're welcome... I'm still not sure how relevant it is, but will keep an eye out for your further feedback.  Cheers.

Comment: @Tony, to indicate my problem using your design - Bar is predefined in Foo<4> as Higher. 1)I need to be able to work with various types of Foo<4>::Higher. 2)and to be able to operate with objects Foo<3> with Higher::Higher Bar1 and with Higher::Higher Bar2 as objects of one type.

Comment: @Riga: for 1) above, you'll work with various "Bar" at run time? So, you have say Bar1 and Bar2, and need Foo<4> to point to an object of either type, but to be able to operate on it in some way?  For 2), to operator with Bar1/Bar2 "as objects of one type" is polymorphism: you use compile time polymorphism - overloading, templated functions, or run-time polymorphism - the language provides virtual functions if you derive Bar1 and Bar2 from an Abstract_Base specifying the common API, or you can consider libraries ala boost variant, any, or RTTI/dynamic_cast as you say.

Comment: @Riga: I've updated the code above to illustrate run-time selection of a Bar1 or Bar2 object.

Comment: @Tony, we are at the entrance point of the discussion now. I don't want to use dynamic_cast, I want Foo<4> to have function get_higher() that returns not AbstractBar*, but Bar1* or Bar2*. My suggestion is that some structure FooOwner can be developed to do this: Foo<4>::Higher is FooOwner, but FooOwner can in turn have abstract virtual function get() that can be overloaded to return derived Bar1. To do this FooOwner can be overloaded on side of Bar1 usage instead of done template, because return type is not a part of function signature and can be changed in implementation.

Comment: @Tony, but my suggestion simply will not compile then used. I see from your code that the only thing one can do to avoid dynamic casting is to overload common interface by each owner class so implementations can be invoked implicitly. So the answer could be - if you want objects to be used in the same context, explicitly define interface to use them in this context and all other approaches will do some unclear hacks. Maybe it is so...

Comment: @Riga: "get_higher()...returns...not AbstractBar*, but Bar1* or Bar2*".  In reality it is returning one of those, it's just that because at run-time it could be either one the calling code can only initially rely on the common interface as specified through AbstractBar*.  If the code calling `get_higher()` wants separate code compiled for each type, it must use `dynamic_cast<>`, an `enum` or some other way to differentiate Bar1 from Bar2.  For the FooOwner you postulate with virtual get() to return Bar1* means it can't work when Higher is a Bar2.

Comment: "return type...changed in implementation": the only change allowed is for covariant return types (which means you promise to return an `AbstractBar*` but actually return `Bar1*` or `Bar2*`), but when you only have run-time knowledge that either `Bar1*` or `Bar2*` could be returned then specifying a covariant return type makes no difference!  All covariant return types do is preserve compile-time knowledge of which derived class is implementing a virtual function, but if you don't know that at compile time there's nothing to preserve.

Comment: "Maybe it is so" - if you consider `dynamic_cast<>`, a type-encoding `enum`/`int` etc. to be unclear hacks, then yes, it is so: you can't switch on a type not known at compile-time without some switching mechanism operating on discriminatory data - whether any of the above or a pointer to a virtual dispatch table/RTTI, function pointers etc..  Some existing libraries can provide a nicer interface over these approaches: boost `any` and `variant` being good examples: you really should play with both and see if they feel less "hacky" to you.  But, `virtual` is the main language-provided feature.

Comment: @Tony, thank you for your time, sorry I cannot benefit you because of my low rating. I ended up with double dispatch. If I add virtual void apply(FooOwnerVisitor*) = 0; function to FooOwner, then I can add any functionality for FooOwner derivatives without affecting FooN hierarchy.

Comment: @Riga: you're welcome.  Glad you found what you wanted.  Cheers.